# Changing the method from wcscpy to wcscpy_s

Tags: c++

I changed the lines from this:

```
wcscpy(buffer, ppath);
```

To:

```
size_t len3 = wcslen(buffer);
wcscpy_s(buffer, len3, ppath);
```

The system is crashing and generating dump files.
Can you suggest any safe alternative to this?

It is a part of an enterprise application that was developed in VS 2010 C++. Now, the company wants to migrate its project to the latest Visual Studio.

It consists of one more methods which use `wcscat()`. If the above problem will get resolved then will, too.

I cannot disclose any other info. If any extra info is required, let me know. Based on the required info, I'll respond.

Comment: The `size_t len3 = wcslen(buffer);` will return the length of the null-terminated string data that is currently in the `buffer` array. You need to specify the **capacity** of that buffer in the call to `wcscpy_s`. Without more code, we can't tell you how to determine that but it will likely be the declared size of the array.

Comment: Just a note, but due to it being an enterprise app, you should look at the license all SO answers are under: https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing

Comment: Unless you want to overwrite `buffer` with a new string that is at most of the same length as the string that is already there, that is very wrong.

Comment: Also note that the call to `wcslen` will fail and/or crash the program if the given buffer is not a properly null-terminated string.

Comment: "system is crashing and generating dump files" - lucky you - then you have something to load into your debugger to see where and why It crashes. Bugs that reproducibly produce crash dumps are usually the easiest ones to fix.

Answer (score 1):

In `wcscpy(buffer, ppath);`, you are copying the contents of the null-terminated string `ppath` into `buffer`, regardless of what is already contained in `buffer`.  This is perfectly safe if `buffer` has not been initialized yet (provided `ppath` is not larger than `buffer`) since you are simply overwriting what is in `buffer`.

However, `wcslen(buffer)` requires `buffer` to contain a null-terminated string. But if `buffer` has not been initialized yet, then this call is *undefined behavior*.

`wcscpy_s()` expects the specified size to be the allocated capacity of the `buffer`, not the size of its current contents. So, you need to use `sizeof()` instead of `wcslen()` (assuming that `buffer` is a fixed array and not allocated dynamically, otherwise use the allocated size instead):

```
wcscpy_s(buffer, sizeof(buffer), ppath);
```

If indeed `buffer` is a fixed array, then you can simplify this by omitting the size parameter altogether and let `wcscpy_s()` deduce the required size for you (this only works in C++, not in C, but you did mark the question as C++, so...):

```
wcscpy_s(buffer, ppath);
```